# A better way to initialize List<String> with repeated char in java

Tags: java, list

Does anyone knows an easy way to initialize `List<String>` with repeated char in java?
What I am thinking is, for example, I wanna initialize a size n List with n '.':

```
char[] c = new char[n];
Arrays.fill(c,'.');
String s = new String(c);
List<String> board = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(n,s));
```

Seems pretty complicated though. Cause in C++, we can just use

```
vector<string> board(n,string(n,'.'));
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to result to be. You say you want a list of repeated chars but your java code is creating a list of repeated strings each with repeated chars.

Comment: Try `List<String> board = Collections.nCopies(n, new String(new char[n]).replace("\0", "."));`.

Comment: `StringUtils.repeat` (common-lang) et `Collections.nCopies` should do the job

Answer (score 0):

You could create a stream from 1 to n, use map to convert to a new String Object, and collect them to a List. Simple and clean.

```
List<String> board = IntStream.range(1, n)
    .mapToObj(i -> ".")
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `new String(".")` is redundant, it should be just `"."`.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Duly noted, and edited accordingly. Thanks!